# Elevated commands within a script

Tags: windows-7, user-permissions

I have a build script which runs within visual studio.  As part of the script i need to register a DLL with **regsrv32**, however this needs to be done with elevated privileges.

When we did this under **XP**, since all users on our domain are local administrators, regsrv32 always succedded, however under **Windows 7** it fails as the script runs with the standard user privileges.

I looked at using **RunAs**, however this doesn't seem to work correctly, and only runs as the account specified, not the current user with elevated privileges.

Does anybody know of a way of elevating a single command within a script?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get an answer off-line?
RunAs doesn't work in Win7 either, even if you create another user as a member of Administrators, because he still needs to be "elevated". Sysinternals ShellRunAs has an "enumerate priviledges" option which only lists one "Basic User", even in an elevated command window - useless!

---

PS The only workaround I could find was to set the batch-file's shortcut to "Run as Administrator" though the resultant elevation dialog is annoying.